# Why is API Gateway not substituting my path variable when sending to my proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I would expect it to send my request to `http://<removed>/search/qweqweqweqwe`, not to `http://<removed>/search/{searchString}`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Mon May 06 13:18:59 UTC 2019 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /search/qweqweqweqwe
Mon May 06 13:18:59 UTC 2019 : Method request path: {searchString=qweqweqweqwe}
Mon May 06 13:18:59 UTC 2019 : Method request query string: {}
Mon May 06 13:18:59 UTC 2019 : Method request headers: {}
Mon May 06 13:18:59 UTC 2019 : Method request body before transformations: 
Mon May 06 13:19:00 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request URI: http://<removed>/search/{searchString}
Mon May 06 13:19:00 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=bx0tw55ts0, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_bx0tw55ts0}
Mon May 06 13:19:00 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
Mon May 06 13:19:00 UTC 2019 : Sending request to http://<removed>/search/{searchString}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you are using http_proxy on API Gateway, you have to create a URL Path Parameter in the Integration Request section. Once I added `searchString` as the variable, and `method.request.path.searchString`, it worked as expected.

Now I just have to figure out how I can define that in the swagger api doc and have it work on import.